# Is there a way to use regular expressions in the replacement string in re.sub() in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, substring

In Python in the `re` module there is the following function:

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0) – Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged.

I've found it can work like this:

```
print re.sub('[a-z]*\d+','lion','zebra432') # prints 'lion'
```

I was wondering, is there an easy way to use regular expressions in the replacement string, so that the replacement string contains part of the original regular expression/original string? Specifically, can I do something like this (which doesn't work)?

```
print re.sub('[a-z]*\d+', 'lion\d+', 'zebra432')
```

I want that to print `'lion432'`. Obviously, it does not. Rather, it prints `'lion\d+'`. Is there an easy way to use parts of the matching regular expression in the replacement string?

By the way, this is NOT a special case. Please do NOT assume that the number will always come at the end, the words will always come in the beginning, etc. I want to know a solution to all regexes in general.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place `\d+` in a capture group `(...)` and then use `\1` to refer to it:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[a-z]*(\d+)', r'lion\1', 'zebra432')
'lion432'
>>>
>>> # You can also refer to more than one capture group
>>> re.sub('([a-z]*)(\d+)', r'\1lion\2', 'zebra432')
'zebralion432'
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched
>   by group `6` in the pattern.

Note that you will also need to use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) so that `\1` is not treated as an escape sequence.

Comment: Should a raw string not also be used for the regex (the first string)?

Comment: @DavidZwicker - Probably.  But it is not strictly necessary here.

Comment: zebralions are pretty much my favorite animal.